# Problem with Amazon SP-API estimateTransport

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-mws, amazon-selling-partner-api

I am having trouble getting estimateTransport() to work
It is returning
`FTXGatewayService.estimateLtlShipment returned error code: 412`

Why?

The ShipmentType of Small Parcel / "SP" works, but "LTL" does not.

The Amazon workflow says to first
PUT to fba/inbound/v0/shipments/FBAxxxx/transport
Then
POST to fba/inbound/v0/shipments/FBAxxxx/estimate

```
Body for the PUT to transport:
{
    "IsPartnered": true,
    "ShipmentType": "LTL",
    "TransportDetails": {
        "PartneredLtlData": {
            "Contact": {
                "Name": "Test1",
                "Phone": "234-343-3434",
                "Email": "abc@test.com",
                "Fax": "234-343-3434"
            },
            "BoxCount": 1,
            "SellerFreightClass": "50",
            "FreightReadyDate": "2022-12-25",
            "PalletList": [{
                    "Dimensions": {
                        "Length": 13,
                        "Width": 13,
                        "Height": 13,
                        "Unit": "inches"
                    },
                    "Weight": {
                        "Value": 13,
                        "Unit": "pounds"
                    },
                    "IsStacked": true
                }
            ],
            "TotalWeight": {
                "Value": 13,
                "Unit": "pounds"
            },
            "SellerDeclaredValue": {
                "CurrencyCode": "USD",
                "Value": 20
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just got this error today. Error code 412 indicates a problem with the size or weight of the box. For me, forgetting the decimal point meant my box was entered as 2820 pounds when it was actually 28.20. For you, I would assume that Amazon considers a 13 X 13 X 13 pallet weighing 13 pounds too small for an LTL delivery.

Comment: The dimensions & weight are from the Sandbox parameters.
But, yes, I was not following some of the undocumented business rules.

Answer (score 0):

For future readers, the problem is not following the undocumented constraints.

Stackable Pallet
Pallet weight between 150 and 750 lb
Height between 1 and 50 in.

Non-Stacking Pallet
Pallet weight between 150 and 1500 lb.
Height between 1 and 72 in.